# don't understand difference between df.shape and df.value_counts().sum()

Tags: python, pandas

When I do the following df.shape output 1881 rows and when I perform value_count() on the same dataframe I end up with 1844. Could you tell me why?
Thanks for your insights.

```
dfSPSSstudent.loc[:,'QX_7_1':'QX_7_4']= dfSPSSstudent.loc[:,'QX_7_1':'QX_7_4'][(dfSPSSstudent.loc[:,'QX_7_1':'QX_7_4'] != -99).all(axis=1)]
print(dfSPSSstudent['QX_7_3'].value_counts().sum())
```

Comment: if you have nulls in the dataframe, value_counts will exclude them. Having a look at the documentation for the function usually points you to possible reasons. Try value_counts with dropna set to False and see if the output matches

Answer (score -1):

OK I have found the issue the -99 are transformed in NAN values. Simple :-)

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.